# Can I specifiy a "target" for a Coldfusion template which is inserted from application.cfc

Tags: templates, authentication, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, application.cfc

Just wondering (Coldfusion Newbie). I'm on this [page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appSecurity_15.html), showing an example how to setup a user login/logout in Coldfusion.

Simple question:

If the user is not logged in, the application.cfc inserts a login form.

**Question:**
Is there any way to set a *target* where this login form ends up? Some target/selector/anything to make it show up where it's supposed to?

Thanks for infos!

Comment: or can I just drop the cffunction and template whereever I want on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that code is set up it doesn't matter where you point it as the cflogin tag will always catch the request and process it. In pseudocode...

```
if not logged-in (cflogin)
    if not submitting form
        show login form
    else
        process login form
```

Comment: Ok. Got it. In general, do you recommend using cflogin or try coming up with an customized solution?

Comment: I started using CF before cflogin was available and have never felt a need to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also trying my first login without CFLOGIN. If you see more login questions popping up, feel free to input :-)